# masterpage in apache wicket world

Tags: java, asp.net, master-pages, wicket

I am asp.net programmer and I've started a web application in java.
What is the equivalent to asp.net masterpage in java apache wicket project?

Comment: What is a masterpage in asp.net? In wicket you can use inheritance / composition to build up your pages.

Comment: @bert: Master page is like a base page where each other page that uses that masterpage should fill only the contect without worry for the header, footer and all the other equal contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can / have to make your own Master Page.

In my apps I have a `BaseTemplate` class. The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
>
<head>
    <title wicket:id="pagetitle"></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <wicket:child />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can do general stuff like the `pagetitle` in the `BaseTemplate` class.

`<wicket:child />` let's you fill in content from another page. You have to subclass `BaseTemplate` and use the `<wicket:extend>content goes here</wicket:extend>` -tag for the HTML of the subclass(es).